# Getting error Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm experiencing this error when I'm trying to set up a countdown for everyday. 
This is my script:

```
var date;
var display = document.getElementById('time');

$(document).ready(function() {
    getTime('GMT', function(time){
        date = new Date(time);
    });    
});

setInterval(function() {
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + 1000);

    var currenthours = date.getHours();
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var seconds;
    if (currenthours != 21){
        if (currenthours < 21) {
            hours = 20 - currenthours;
        } else {
            hours = 21 + (24 - currenthours);
        }
        minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
        seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }

        display.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' +seconds;
     } else { 
        display.innerHTML = 'LIVE NOW';
    }
}, 1000);

function getTime(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}
```

and the line that causes this error is

```
date = new Date(date.getTime() + 1000);
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a countdown that resets daily.

Comment: date is initialized under document.ready and `date = new Date(date.getTime() + 1000);` code executed outside. So the code you have written outside document.ready can execute before date initialize. That's the reason you are getting getTime cannot be called on undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getTime` call within the `$(document).ready` takes more than a second to finish which means that the `setInterval` you set before it executes first. Thus, the `date` variable is not set yet.

To fix this, move your `setInterval` call to after you initialize the `date` variable within the callback function to ensure your `date` is always set before the `setInterval` function executes.

```
var date;
var display = document.getElementById('time');

$(document).ready(function() {
    getTime('GMT', function(time){
        date = new Date(time);

        setInterval(function() {
            date = new Date(date.getTime() + 1000);

            var currenthours = date.getHours();
            var hours;
            var minutes;
            var seconds;
            if (currenthours != 21){
                if (currenthours < 21) {
                    hours = 20 - currenthours;
                } else {
                    hours = 21 + (24 - currenthours);
                }
                minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
                seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();

                if (minutes < 10) {
                    minutes = '0' + minutes;
                }
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = '0' + seconds;
                }

                display.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' +seconds;
           } else { 
                display.innerHTML = 'LIVE NOW';
           }
        }, 1000);
    });    
});

function getTime(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}
```